# How to write a Clojure function that returns a list of adjacent pairs?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a function `adjacents` that returns a vector of a sequence's adjacent pairs. So `(adjacents [1 2 3])` would return `[[1 2] [2 3]]`.

```
(defn adjacents [s]
  (loop [[a b :as remaining] s
          acc []]
    (if (empty? b)
      acc
      (recur (rest remaining) (conj acc (vector a b))))))
```

My current implementation works for sequences of strings but with integers or characters the REPL outputs this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:494)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is in the first evaluation loop of `(adjacents [1 2 3])`, `a` is bound to `1` and `b` to `2`. Then you ask if `b` is `empty?`. But `empty?` works on sequences and `b` is not a sequence, it is a `Long`, namely `2`. The predicate you could use for this case here is `nil?`:

```
user=> (defn adjacents [s]
  #_=>   (loop [[a b :as remaining] s acc []]
  #_=>     (if (nil? b)
  #_=>       acc
  #_=>       (recur (rest remaining) (conj acc (vector a b))))))
#'user/adjacents
user=> (adjacents [1 2 3 4 5])
[[1 2] [2 3] [3 4] [4 5]]
```

But, as @amalloy points out, this may fail to give the desired result if you have legitimate `nil`s in your data:

```
user=> (adjacents [1 2 nil 4 5])
[[1 2]]
```

See his comment for suggested implementation using lists.

Note that Clojure's `partition` can be used to do this work without the perils of defining your own:

```
user=> (partition 2 1 [1 2 3 4 5])
((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5))
user=> (partition 2 1 [1 2 nil 4 5])
((1 2) (2 nil) (nil 4) (4 5))
```

Comment: Testing b for `nil?` is disastrous, because now you can't compute `(adjacents '[x y nil 5 6 7])` or similar. Instead, you need to work with lists, eg by `(loop [[x & xs] remaining] (if xs (let [y (first xs)] ...)))`.

Comment: True enough, this was merely the adjustment to the OP's code with the smallest Levenshtein distance to address the case in question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my short answer. Everything becomes a vector, but it works for all sequences.

```
(defn adjacent-pairs [s] 
  {:pre [(sequential? s)]}
  (map vector (butlast s) (rest s)))
```

Testing:

```
user=> (defn adjacent-pairs [s] (map vector (butlast s) (rest s))) 
#'user/adjacent-pairs
user=> (adjacent-pairs '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
([1 2] [2 3] [3 4] [4 5] [5 6])
user=> (adjacent-pairs [1 2 3 4 5 6])
([1 2] [2 3] [3 4] [4 5] [5 6])
user=>
```

This answer is probably less efficient than the one using `partition` above, however.